# Передача сигнала на USB

Tags: c++, windows, usb

Можно ли в C++ реализовать передачу сигнала на USB?
И с помощью каких библиотек это можно реализовать?

Comment: Рекомендую указать операционную систему, от ОС сильно зависят и средства

Comment: Windows, до *nix далеко.

Comment: А теперь сразу и второй вопрос - а что за сигнал собрались передавать? Просто питание на вывод подать? Или девайс какой-нибудь подключить?

Comment: Питание для звонка.

Comment: там и так уже есть 5 вольт - вот и питание.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я, наверное, неправильно поставил задачу. Подавать питание нужно только в определенный момент и определенное кол-во секунд.
Пример: 
9:00 - звонок продолжительностью 5 секунд.

Comment: Просто так взять и подключить звонок к usb - нельзя. USB предназначен для приема-передачи данных. Поэтому эту задачу обычно решают так - берут arduino, на котором есть usb порт, им соединяют с компом. А на самой адруине с помощью реле уже управляют нагрузкой.
вот почти готовый пример http://robocraft.ru/blog/544.html

Comment: Реле припаяно к самому USB (придумано не мной.) Единственный вопрос - подача сигнала. А вообще, производите впечатление знающего человека, можно ли связаться вне форума?(Если вас не затруднит, конечно.)

Comment: Вообще проще написать для самой винды прогу, чтобы она в 9 утра сигнал подавала, хотя бы системный MessageBeep(). Но если вам все же надо поуправлять USB, то MSDN вам в руки https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff728834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: *"Реле припаяно к самому USB (придумано не мной)"* Передайте тому человеку, который так придумал, что он - идиот! Так с USB-портами поступать не следует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без микроконтроллера подключиться к USB так, чтобы вся связка работала правильно и надежно - не получится. Если у вас "просто реле припаяно к USB" - отпаивайте, и поищите переходник.

В продаже можно найти USB-COM или USB-LPT переходники. При подключении к компьютеру они "видны" как дополнительные COM- или LPT-порты. Вот к ним уже можно припаивать реле, протокол позволяет. Только выходные токи проверьте.

В случае COM-порта у вас есть пины DTR и RTS для управления релюшкой и DSR, CTS, DCD и RI для приема сигналов. Ну, это если не считать RxD/TxD - но они для "релюшной" логики слабо пригодны.

В случае LPT у вас есть аж 8 проводов, которые могут работать как на вход, так и на выход - но там понадобится "хитрая" логика согласования режима, без которой стандартный виндовый драйвер не даст вам переключить порт на нужный режим работы. По крайней мере, мне этого добиться не удалось - поэтому рассчитывайте на 8 выходных пинов и на 1 входной (статусный).

Comment: Спасибо, последую вашему совету, скорее всего.

Comment: а есть ли какой-нибудь гайд о управлении DTR  ?

Comment: @GoldenCobra https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx - тут общая информация. Правда, для вас там большая часть будет бесполезна - вам же данные передавать не надо...

Comment: @GoldenCobra Конкретно DTR устанавливает функция [SetCommState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363436(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Т.е. можно смело тратиться на USB-COM и быть уверенным, что звонок зазвенит? (Если сделать все правильно с моей стороны.)

Answer (score 2):

Просто так из Windows поуправлять ножками разъема USB в общем случае не получится - это не LPT или COM, где железо простое как мычание.

Вам потребуется какое-нибудь оконечное устройство, которое будет управляться по USB и подключать звонок. Таким устройством может быть уже классическая макетка ARDUINO, либо один из конвертеров USB - RS232, на базе чипа 
CP2103 или FTDI.

Для этих чипов производитель выпускает библиотеки DLL, которые дают возможность управлять ножками чипа непосредственно.

У меня есть самописная обертка над этими DLL, написанная на CPP.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае - WinUSB API (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinUSB). Если устройство "generic" (не соответствует никакому стандартному классу) то нужно на него ассоциировать стандартный драйвер WinUSB (для любых классов кроме HID это тоже верно). Сделать это можно вручную при помощи Zadig или программно, при помощи библиотеки libwdi, на базе которой и построен Zadig, как пример: https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi и https://github.com/pbatard/libwdi/wiki/Zadig. Либо, как альтернатива, реализовать HID устройство (и да, это не обязательно мышка или клавиатура, читаем: http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/), тогда драйвера поставятся автоматически.

Я напрямую WinUSB API не использовал, только через libusb (приложение кросс платформенное), но под винду в такой связке есть проблемы (рандомные), которые выражаются в невозможности общения с устройством. Вроде как, при этом, напрямую через WinUSB существуют разные обходные пути.

Плюс, если в вашем случае нужно только командовать что-то сделать (посылка на уровне одного байта), то даже сильно заморачиваться с дескрипторами USB не нужно, хватат стандартного набора, а данные обрабатывать через Control Endpoint 0 (EP0).

Ещё один вариант, реализовать CDC класс и общаться с устройством как с простым последовательным портом со стороны хоста.

Как вы уже могли заметить: нужно искать компромисс. Усложнение работы на хосте (установка драйвера, добавление данного функционала в приложение, какая-то эвристика, обработка косяков хост-конроллеров и т.д.) приводит к упрощению обработки на устройстве (только стандартные дескрипторы и только EP0). Усложнение обработки на устройстве (реализация HID, CDC и т.п.) позволяет значительно упросить клиентское приложение на хосте.

Да, всё вышесказанное верно только в том случае, если у вас на той стороне что-то, что может работать по протоколу USB. В случае сиииильной нужды хвататит ATTiny2313 с кварцем на 16Mhz (обязательно) и софтварным стеком USB, места хватит на стек и байт 300-400 останется для вашего обработчика, т.к. его логика примитивна: дать и снять уровень на одной ноге, то этого места хватит за глаза. Для управления реле потребуется добавить один транзистор в качестве ключа, что бы не спалить ногу контроллера. Я такое делал в полном стеке (железо /схема, пайка/, прошивка, софт на PC /Linux, Windows/): индикация прихода новой почты :) Потом это же использовал (уже с ключём и реле) для управления напольным вентилятором (220 В). А вот вам и туториал в тему: http://codeandlife.com/2012/01/22/avr-attiny-usb-tutorial-part-1/ и дальше по ссылкам.